# где находятся файлы обьектов базы данных на сайте на Rails

Tags: база-данных, файлы, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, восстановление

есть папка с проектом сайта на Ruby on Rails
https://yadi.sk/d/lqiNsdfw3Gci8Z
есть несколько таблиц, хранящихся в базе данных.
надо определить файлы, в которых хранятся данные из таблиц.
сами таблицы хранятся в папке миграций, это я понимаю.
Где хранятся экземпляры полей таблиц?
*например*, где хранятся экземрляры отзывов, если таблица создана по миграции Opinion.rb в папке db/migrate
*практическое применение:* перед командами

```
rails db:drop
rails db:migrate
```

можно делать бекап файлов, а затем вернуть на прежнее место, и информация не потеряется

---

В проекте используется гем `pg`.

Comment: Вы, видимо, не в курсе, для чего вообще нужен механизм миграций, иначе бы у вас такой вопрос не возник, как бессмысленный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Это бессмысленное действие и не сработает

Скажите мне, зачем вам это надо, и я объясню вам, почему это вам не поможет `:Р`

#### Если вы хотите изменить уже существующую миграцию...

После того, как миграция отправлена в проект и попала хоть куда-то кроме вашей машины, менять её **нельзя** (технически возможно, но последствия придётся долго разгребать). Последующие изменения в схему базы должны производиться уже **новыми миграциями**.

Типичный порядок работы — вы делаете новую миграцию, при деплое делаете только `db:migrate` (никакого `db:drop`!), сервер смотрит какие миграции в проекте есть сейчас, вычитает, какие из них у него уже есть, оставшиеся применяет.

Миграции изначально создаются для того, чтобы менять структуру базы **без потери данных** (или с намеренной потерей ненужных, если надо).

#### Если вы хотите поддерживать в БД данные для тестирования...

...опишите процесс их создания на Ruby в файле `seeds.rb`, который выполняется при запуске Rake-задачи `db:seed`.

---

## Почему так сложно?

Потому что данные в БД хранятся в достаточно сложной структуре, имеющей кучу зависимостей и не предназначенной для грубого "кидания файлов туда-сюда".

Механизм резервных копий вам не поможет, если вы собрались менять миграцию, т. к. резервная копия сохраняет **и структуру тоже**, поверх другой структуры просто так восстановить её не получится. И, как я уже сказал выше, **миграции вообще менять не следует** (во всяком случае, пока вы не поймёте, для чего миграции нужны и когда их следует менять).

Answer (score 0):

Все данные хранятся в базе данных. Если вы используете **postgresql**. То данные находятся в файла на сервер БД. Для создания резервной копии вы можете использовать утилиту `pg_dump`.

Она позволяет сохранять данные из любой БД/таблицы. Имена таблиц будут совпадать с именам указанными в файлах миграций. Имена БД вы можете посмотреть в файле `config/database.yml`